# facebook - reset post feed or app? What is it?

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, share

I don't know what is it or how it's working, but it seems to be something with session or cookie.

I implemented facebook share button on my page (under each post), and if I share it and (in the future) I modify the post on my page (title, description or image) the post on my facebook wall doesn't update itself. If I delete the post (on my page) and I regenerate with the same name (same row id - mysql db), different images, title and I share it, the old post appears.

I made a grammatical mistake in the description meta tag

```
<meta property="og:description" content="asd"/>
```

and I must delete it from my page (from my database) and I must create a new one.

Is there any way to reset the facebook session or cookie or what is it... I don't know.

Comment: Put your page URL through the Debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell facebook about any changes you make to the page or wait for facebook to scrape your page again. The easiest way to update the Facebook Cache for your page is to use the [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) as the administrator of the app.